# Unable to replace content from h2 tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying a fairly simple thing. I want to replace the text inside a h2 tag when the user click on it. My code is just adding an extra h2 element keeping the old content as it is.

```
<?DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var html = "";
    var value = "New Text " 
    $("#sample").click(function(){

        if(value == "Old Text"){
            value = "New Text";
        } else {
            value ="Old Text";
    }

    html += "<h2 id='target'>"+value+"</h2>";
    $("#target").html(html);

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="sample">
<h2 id = "target"> Change this Text </h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, yes, it adds the new content to the element. In other words, you're inserting "<h2 id='target'>New Text</h2>" into the h2.

To insert *only* the text "New Text", all you need to do is

```
$("#target").html(value);
```

instead of

```
$("#target").html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var html = "";
var value = "New Text " 
$("#sample").click(function(){

    if (value == "Old Text") {
        value = "New Text";
    } else {
        value = "Old Text";
    }

    html = "<h2 id='target'>"+value+"</h2>";
    $("#target").html(html);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function(){ 
  
  $('h2').on('click', function(e) {
 
    if(!$(this).hasClass('changed')) {
      
  $(this).text("Text Changed!");
    $(this).addClass('changed');
 }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="">Click to change its text</h2>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the content of `h2`.
You do not need to create another `h2` and add to DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var html = "";
  var value = "New Text "
  $("#sample").click(function() {

    if (value == "Old Text") {
         value = "New Text";
    } else {
         value = "Old Text";
    }

    $("#target").text(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<?DOCTYPE HTML>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sample">
      <h2 id="target"> Change this Text </h2>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

as has already mentioned, you are better off using 'value' here;

```
$("#target").html(value);
```

Additionally it might be useful for you know that you are implicitly asking for this to happen by using += on this line;

```
html += "<h2 id='target'>"+value+"</h2>";
```

In simple terms += means to add something to the end of what already exists, rather than to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the text inside a h2 tag

Use the jQuery `text()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').click(function(){
        $(this).text('You clicked and I changed!');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="target">Click to change this Text...</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, there is no need for #sample as you can run jquery Click function on any ID/class.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var text = ['New Text', 'Old Text'];
var i = -1;

$("#target").click(function(){
    i++; if(i==2) { i = 0; }
    $("#target").html(text[i]);
    });     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id = "target"> Change this Text </h2>
</body>
</html>
```